# find all $a,b \in \mathbb N$ such that $9925-26a^2=b^2$

Tags: contest-math, divisibility

**My Attempt:**

$$9925-26a^2=b^2 \iff 9925=b^2 + 26a^2$$
Since $9925$ is odd and $26a^2$ is even $\implies b^2$ is odd $\implies b^2 = 2n+1$.
$$9925=2n+1+26a^2\iff 9925=2(n+13a^2)+1$$
$$ \iff 4962 = n+13a^2$$

Now We can reword this problem to *Find all $(n, a)\in \mathbb N$ such that $13\mid 4962+\frac{1-b^2}{2}$ and $$\frac{4962+\frac{1-b^2}{2}}{13} = a^2$$*

But the problem is that I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Your last problem is not equivalent to the original one: $n$ can't be arbitrary, it has to be of the form $(b^2-1)/2$

Comment: $\sqrt{9925-26a^2}$ should be a perfect square. Think of a suitable $f(n)$ substitution for $a$.

Comment: It's not difficult to check for natural number solutions between 0 and 20 (this is an ellipse).

Comment: If $b=2n+1$, rather than $b^2$, can you show that $b^2$ is one more than a multiple of $4$?

Comment: Feel free to edit the question if you want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $9925$ equals $6$ modulo $13$. Therefore $b^2$ should also have this remainder modulo $13$, but you can check by hand that this is never possible.

When trying to solve these types of contest math problems with diophantine equations, it's always a good idea to look at it modulo some small (prime) number.